# How to change the width of the column when using <display:column> and when using table-layout:fixed

Tags: css, tablelayout, displaytag

I have specified the width of the column but I dont see any change in the width.Please help me. Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
<div style="height: auto;">
        <display:table style="width:100%; position: relative;left:0px;table-layout:fixed;" pagesize="5">

<display:column sortable="true" style="width: 80%;text-align: left;word-wrap:break-word;">

        </display:column>

        <display:column style="width: 20%;text-align: left;"  title="Date"  />
        </display:table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the width and other css elements in display tag ,because display tag internally uses its own defined css (diplaytag.css) which is invoked when jsp page is compiled.Here

```
<display:table style="width:100%;
```

**width** attribute will not affect the css of displaytag. So you have to made changes in the **displaytag.css** file. do have displaytag.css file in your classpath. if not then add this file in your classpath and give reference to this file using **link** attribute in your jsp file like this.

```
<link href="styles/displaytag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In this css class you'll find a large no. of style-sets, made changes is these style-sets, this will surely make some effects.

If you still facing problem to find out which css is needed to be changes then you can use firebug to check which css is applied on displaytag-elements and make changes in the particular styles sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
<display:column property="propertyNamed" headerClass="sortable" titleKey="title" style="width:100px;"/>
```

It works for me...!